# Check 1:N hierarchy is maintained at 4 levels

Tags: sql, plsql, hana

I have hierarchy level data of 5 levels in a table

```
1.BRANCH
2.LEGAL-ENTITY
3.REPORT-UNIT
4.REGIONAL
5.COUNTRY
```

I have a table which contain records containing all the hierarchy with Branch as the Primary Key.
I need to check if the relationship of 1:n is maintained between higher level hierarchy to low level hierarchy.

```
WHITEFIELD|BANGALORE|KARNATAKA|INDIA|APAC
WHITEFIELD|BANGALORE|MYSORE|INDIA|APAC - WRONG RECORD
MG ROAD|BANGALORE|KARNATAKA|INDIA|APAC
MG ROAD|NEW DELHI|DELHI|INDIA|APAC - WRONG RECORD
SILK BOARD|BANGALORE|KARNATAKA|INDIA|APAC
SILK BOARD|PUNE|MAHARASTRA|INDIA|APAC - WRONG RECORD
```

To achieve this, I want to write one query which can give me records which are not satisfying the above rule.

I have already written a query which can give the result for 4th and 5th level.

```
SELECT COD_BRNC,COUNT(DISTINCT COD_LEGL_ENTT) FROM TDI_GEO_BY_ORIGIN
WHERE COD_BRNC  NOT LIKE '%_D' AND YEAR(DAT_END_GEO_ORGN ) = 9999
GROUP BY COD_BRNC HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT COD_LEGL_ENTT) >  1
```

It gives me

```
SILK BOARD|2
MG ROAD|2
```

Comment: You tagged your question with `plsql` which would indicate an Oracle database. But you also tagged it with `hana` which is a completely different DBMS. Which one is it?

Comment: the code i want to run is on HANA but the same scenario can come for oracle people also and the SQL syntax for both HANA and Oracle is same so i tagged Hana.

Comment: different dbms will never act completely equal, even if the syntax looks like it. You should only use `plsql` or `hana` as @a_horse_with_no_name suggests. People can then use the sql as a reference for other dbms if they want to.

Comment: Can we focus on finding the logic to solve this problem , what syntax to run which database to use is not the important question .. important thing is how will you solve it ,,

Answer (score 0):

Your first query is a good start.
As you did not give a complete Table description I created my own testcase:

```
DROP TABLE level_5_test;

CREATE TABLE level_5_test( branch_id    VARCHAR2( 3 )
                     , level_1      VARCHAR2( 3 )
                     , level_2      VARCHAR2( 3 )
                     , level_3      VARCHAR2( 3 )
                     , level_4      VARCHAR2( 3 )
                     , description  VARCHAR2( 30 )
                      );

INSERT INTO level_5_test
 VALUES ( 'B0', 'L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4', 'No Problems' );

INSERT INTO level_5_test
 VALUES ( 'B1', 'L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4', 'Level 1 Problems' );

INSERT INTO level_5_test
     VALUES ( 'B1', 'E1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4', 'Level 1 Problems' );

INSERT INTO level_5_test
     VALUES ( 'B2', 'L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4', 'Level 2 Problems' );

INSERT INTO level_5_test
     VALUES ( 'B2', 'L1', 'E2', 'L3', 'L4', 'Level 2 Problems' );

INSERT INTO level_5_test
     VALUES ( 'B3', 'L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4', 'Level 3 Problems' );

INSERT INTO level_5_test
     VALUES ( 'B3', 'L1', 'L2', 'E3', 'L4', 'Level 3 Problems' );

INSERT INTO level_5_test
     VALUES ( 'B4', 'L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4', 'Level 4 Problems' );

INSERT INTO level_5_test
     VALUES ( 'B4', 'L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'E4', 'Level 4 Problems' );

INSERT INTO level_5_test
     VALUES ( 'B5', 'L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'E4', 'Double Problems' );

INSERT INTO level_5_test
     VALUES ( 'B5', 'L1', 'E2', 'L3', 'L4', 'Double Problems' );

COMMIT;
--
```

The best way to get all the answers is by querying all fields and adding the analytic variations of count(distinct...) where you partition by the branch_id:

```
WITH level_query
     AS (SELECT branch_id
              , level_1
              , level_2
              , level_3
              , level_4
              , description
              , COUNT( DISTINCT level_1 ) OVER (PARTITION BY branch_id)
                   AS level_1_count
              , COUNT( DISTINCT level_2 ) OVER (PARTITION BY branch_id)
                   AS level_2_count
              , COUNT( DISTINCT level_3 ) OVER (PARTITION BY branch_id)
                   AS level_3_count
              , COUNT( DISTINCT level_4 ) OVER (PARTITION BY branch_id)
               AS level_4_count
       FROM level_5_test)
SELECT *
  FROM level_query
 WHERE level_1_count > 1
    OR level_2_count > 1
    OR level_3_count > 1
    OR level_4_count > 1;
```

This works for Oracle, but might not work (yet) for Hana. Then you have to combine four queries with UNION ALL

```
SELECT   'L1' AS level_name
       , branch_id
    FROM level_5_test
GROUP BY branch_id
  HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT level_1 ) > 1
UNION ALL
SELECT   'L2' AS level_name
       , branch_id
    FROM level_5_test
GROUP BY branch_id
  HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT level_2 ) > 1
UNION ALL
SELECT   'L3' AS level_name
       , branch_id
    FROM level_5_test
GROUP BY branch_id
  HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT level_3 ) > 1
UNION ALL
SELECT   'L4' AS level_name
       , branch_id
    FROM level_5_test
GROUP BY branch_id
  HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT level_4 ) > 1
ORDER BY 2, 1;
```

The first solution needs only one full table scan, the second query needs *four* and would need a fifth FTS to give as much information as the first!